# Is it safe for crawling blogger label url like "/search/label/"?

Tags: label, blogger

Question about blogger SEO, can I disallow the URL like /search or /label from crawlers and should I go through the allow tag?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I will not recommend to disallow  "/search or /label". It will stop the search bot from navigating to your website. If you are managing a site map, then you can block it. It might improve your ranking as you are not indexing useless pages.

You can read reference:

- https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/intro
- https://www.robotstxt.org/